# Is there a ApacheDS 2.0 OSGI version?

Tags: ldap, osgi, osgi-bundle, apacheds, embedded-osgi

I am using ApacheDS 2.0 and looking for OSGI version so that I can use it in OSGI container. I was not able to find one. Anyone else know if there is one out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache ds showing up here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.server are already bundles and have what looks like decent MANIFEST files.

Comment: Thanks. Although I was looking for apacheds-all OSGI artifact. I came across a thread where they said it will be OSGI in 3.0 version.